Creating a frozen present state user report in salesforce
I am trying to produce a present state frozen user report in salesforce but when I run the query to join Objects "INVALID_FIELD:
SELECT User__r.Name, IsFrozen FROM UserLogin
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
Didn't understand relationship 'User__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
I get this error above.
I have tried to make a custom report type and join UserLogin and User but found out Salesforce will let me do this then I tried running quires in workbench, data loader, and developer counsel. I am a system Admin in the Org and have all the required permission s to see this object but can only see it in data loader or workbench not the salesforce UI.
I can pull the frozen users using only the UserLogin Object but only get the Users ID so would have to do another query on user and then do a V lookup. I need away to do this in one query or better yet create a custom report.

Yes, this one is bit clunky. If you run describes you'll see there's no "relationshipName" for going "up" (SELECT User.Name FROM UserLogin won't compile).

and similarly no related list name when trying to go "down" from User.
Your best shot would be something like
SELECT Id, Name, Email, IsActive
FROM User
WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserId FROM UserLogin WHERE IsFrozen = true)

And then use it in code... It'd be rubbish but how about nightly scheduled job looking at this and ticking/unticking a checkbox on users and 5 minutes later - scheduled report running off the helper field?
